# evaluate limit $2x-3(x+1)^{2/3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to evaluate
$\lim _{x \to +\infty } 2x-3(x+1)^{2/3} $ 
and this is what I did 
$\lim _{x \to +\infty } 2x-3(x+1)^{2/3} = \lim _{x \to +\infty } 2x-3\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2} $
$=\lim _{x \to +\infty } \frac{8x^3-27(x+1)^{2}}{4x^2+6x\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}+9\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^4}} $ 
$=\lim _{x \to +\infty } \frac{8x^3-27x^2-54x-27}{4x^2+6x\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}+9\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^4}} $ 
$=\lim _{x \to +\infty } \frac{x^3(8-\frac{27}{x}-\frac{54}{x^2}-\frac{27}{x^3})}{x^3(\frac{4}{x}+6\sqrt[3]{(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3})^2}+9\sqrt[3]{x+4+\frac{6}{x}+\frac{4}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}})} $
$=0$ 
I know it's wrong because the result must be $+\infty$ but I don't know where did I make the mistake. Can you help me please.

Comment: You can just divide by $x$, it would be simpler: the limit of $2x-3(x+1)^{2/3}$ is the limit of $x (2 - 3(\frac {1}{\sqrt {x} } + \frac {1}{x^{3/2}} )$, which is clearly $+ \infty$.

Comment: @RicardoMM Your algebra isn't quite right, but your result is correct.

Comment: but I want to know where is the mistake?

Comment: @user579102 can I ask what are you doing in the first step? (how did you construct that fraction)

Comment: I used this formula : $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$

Comment: @RobertShore I meant to keep the power, so: $ x (2 - 3 \left ( \frac {1}{\sqrt {x} } + \frac {1}{x^{3/2}}  \right )^{2/3} )$.

Comment: You are not factoring out correctly the powers. For instance, $6\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}=6x^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{(1+\frac1x)^2}$ and $9\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^4}=9x^{4/3}\sqrt[3]{(1+\frac1x)^4}$. Then, if you want to factor out an $x^3$, you have to deal with it in similar fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the second to last equality. You factored out $x^3$ of $\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^4}$ leaving a leading $x$ term under the root. This is not correct, since $x^3 =\sqrt[3]{x^9}$ and the leading term of $(x+1)^4$ is a fourth power. You should have written:

$$ \sqrt[3]{(x+1)^4}= x^3 \sqrt[3]{\frac {1}{x^5} + \cdots }$$ instead of:

$$ \sqrt[3]{(x+1)^4}= x^3 \sqrt[3]{x+ \cdots }$$

But, like others have pointed out in the comments, the construction of this fraction is not the way to go, there are more easy ways to check this limit.

Answer (score 1):

Since the answer of RicardoMM responds to the *where-did-I-go-wrong* question, it becomes open-season to present a (**very basic**) $~M, X(M),~$ proof that the function is strictly increasing and grows unbounded.

Let $~\displaystyle f(x) = 2x - 3(x+1)^{(2/3)} \implies 
f'(x) = 2 - \frac{2}{(x+1)^{(1/3)}}.$

Therefore, $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on all of $\Bbb{R^+}.$

For any $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ let
$\displaystyle g(n) = f\left[(10)^{(3n)} - 1\right] \implies $

$$g(n) = 2\left[(10)^{(3n)} - 1\right] - 3\left[10^{(2n)}\right] > 10^{(2n)}.$$

For any $M > 0$, choose $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ such that $(10)^n > M.$

Then, set $X(M) = \left[(10)^{(3n)} - 1\right].$

Then, $f\left[X(M)\right] = g(n) > 10^{(2n)} > 10^n > M.$

Further, since $f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function on $~\Bbb{R^+},~$ 
you have that 
for all $~x > X(M),~f(x) > f\left[X(M)\right] > M.$

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

$$\text{write }2 x-3 (x+1)^{2/3} \text{as }:\qquad x \left(2-\frac{3 (x+1)^{2/3}}{x}\right)$$

Thence now we have

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} x \left(2-\frac{3 (x+1)^{2/3}}{x}\right)$$

But since $(x+1)^{2/3}$ grows asymptotically slower than the polynomial $x$, as $x\to +\infty$, we have:

$$\underset{x\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{(x+1)^{2/3}}{x}=0$$

Whence $$\lim_{x\to+\infty} 2x = +\infty$$